# How to transfer charged amount to a connected stripe account?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am using stripe in test mode and I can't transfert the amount charged to a connected account.

After a successful payment, stripe send the wehook event `checkout.session.completed`, so my backend tries to handle this and transfert the collected amount to the connected account but nothing happens and my platform end up to receive the whole amount. I don't know what's wrong :

```
await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
                    eventData.object.payment_intent,
                    {application_fee_amount: Math.round(0.05 * price),transfer_data: {
                      destination: stripe_connected_account,amount:Math.round(0.95 * price)
                    }}
                  );
```

The above operation is not executed and my connected account receive nothing.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to transfer the funds captured through this Checkout Session to a connected account, you'll need to include the `transfer_data.destionation` and `application_fee_amount` as `payment_intent_data` when creating the Checkout Session:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data

Comment: Yes I already done this. forgot to mention in my post.

Comment: Your snippet shows a call to update a payment intent. This kind of transfer can't be done after payment is already complete. You need to indicate this when *creating the checkout session* as @LauraT noted.